# executing an annotated @Async function twice results in only one of the functions working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have a `watchDirectoryService` which listens to changes in a specified directory, once those events are triggered, I run a process based on an implementation of an interface passed into the async `processEvents` function, but for some reason it is the last executed function that gets triggered/works yet both processes seems to be running in the background as expected, if I comment out one of the async `processEvents` functions, the uncommented function works just fine. I'll put the code below, which consists of 3 classes.

1. `watchDirectoryService` handles listening to changes in a set of directories that can be registered and once the event is triggered it calls an implementation to perform a certain task
2. `Process1Service` implement `process` interface which performs a particular task
3. `Process2Service` implements `process` interface which performs a different set of tasks as well

WatchDirectoryService

```
public class WatchDirService {

    private WatchService watcher;
    private final Map<WatchKey, Path> keys = new HashMap<>();
    private boolean recursive;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static <T> WatchEvent<T> cast(WatchEvent<?> event) {
        return (WatchEvent<T>) event;
    }

    /**
     * Register the given directory with the WatchService
     *
     * @param dir
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    private void register(Path dir) throws IOException {
        WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);

        log.info("PUTTING KEY :: {}", dir);
        keys.putIfAbsent(key, dir);
        log.info("KEY COUNT :: {}", keys.size());
    }

    /**
     * Register the given directory, and all its sub-directories, with the
     * WatchService.
     */
    private void registerAll(final Path start) throws IOException {
        // register directory and sub-directories
        Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                    throws IOException {
                register(dir);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Creates a WatchService and registers the given directory
     *
     * @param dir
     * @param recursive
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public void register(Path dir, boolean recursive) throws IOException {
        this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        this.recursive = recursive;

        if (recursive) {
            log.info("Scanning {} ...\n", dir);
            registerAll(dir);
            log.info("Done.");
        } else {
            log.info("Scanning no recursion {} ...\n", dir);
            register(dir);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process all events for keys queued to the watcher
     *
     * @param processor
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @Async
    public void processEvents(Processor processor) throws Exception {
        log.info("KEY COUNT AND TYPE :: {} {}", keys.size(), processor.getType());

        if (keys.isEmpty()) {
            usage();
        }

        while (true) {
            log.info("==PROCESSING=={}",processor.getType());
            // wait for key to be signalled
            WatchKey key;
            try {
                key = watcher.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                return;
            }

            Path dir = keys.get(key);
            if (dir == null) {
                log.error("WatchKey not recognized!!");
                continue;
            }
            log.info("PROCESSING DIR :: {}", dir);
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

                // TBD - provide example of how OVERFLOW event is handled
                if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
                WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
                Path name = ev.context();
                Path child = dir.resolve(name);

                // print out event
                log.info("%{}: %{}\n", event.kind().name(), child);
                // here you would start batch process

                processor.run(child.toString());

                // if directory is created, and watching recursively, then
                // register it and its sub-directories
                if (recursive && (kind == ENTRY_CREATE)) {
                    try {
                        if (Files.isDirectory(child, NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                            registerAll(child);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException x) {
                        // ignore to keep sample readbale
                    }
                }
            }

            // reset key and remove from set if directory no longer accessible
            boolean valid = key.reset();
            if (!valid) {
                keys.remove(key);

                // all directories are inaccessible
                if (keys.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        log.info("===ENDING PROCESS FOR {}===", processor.getType());
    }

    private void usage() {
        log.error("usage: java WatchDir [-r] dir");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Process1Service

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DecryptEncryptedFileProcessor implements Processor<DecryptFile> {

    @Getter
    private final DecryptFile command;

    @Override
    public void run(String... params) {

        if (params[0] == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No parameter found to decrypt file, expecting at least one parameter that contains encrypted file");
        }

        FileDecoder f = new FileDecoder();
        f.autoBatchDecrypt(params[0],
                command.getDecryptedFileLocation(),
                command.getDecryptedFileExtension(),
                command.getPrefix());
    }
    // shortened

}
```

Process2Service

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProcessDecryptedFileProcessor implements Processor {

//    private JobRepository jobRepository;
    private final SpringBatchConfig config;
    private ItemProcessor<TxnItem, TransactionRecord> processor;

    @Override
    public void run(String... params) {

        if (params[0] == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No decrypted file passed for processing, expecting at least one parameter which contains a decrypted file");
        }

        Path toPath = new File(params[0]).toPath();
        String data = readFromInputStream(toPath);
        log.info("DECRYPTED DATA :: {}", data);
    }

   // shortened
   
}
```

how I execute the functions

```
@Autowired
    public Resources(
            CypherDirectoryConfiguration cypherConfig,
            WatchDirService watchService) throws IOException, Exception {
        this.config = config;
        this.cypherConfig = cypherConfig;
        this.watchService = watchService;

        Path encryptedDir = new File(this.cypherConfig.getEncryptedDir()).toPath();
        Path decryptedDir = new File(this.cypherConfig.getDecryptedDir()).toPath();

        DecryptFile command = new DecryptFile(this.cypherConfig.getDecryptedDir());

        DecryptEncryptedFileProcessor dfp = new DecryptEncryptedFileProcessor(command);
        ProcessDecryptedFileProcessor pdfp = new ProcessDecryptedFileProcessor(this.config);

        log.info("====STARTING WATCH ENCRYPTED DIR====");
        this.watchService.register(encryptedDir, false);
        this.watchService.processEvents(dfp);

        log.info("====STARTING WATCH DECRYPTED DIR====");
        this.watchService.register(decryptedDir, false);
        this.watchService.processEvents(pdfp);
    }
```

Comment: `WatchService` is a singleton... The first thing that the `register` method does is, create a new watcher, destroying to old one. If you want multiple to run, you will need multiple instances.

Comment: Thanks this clarified things for me @M.Deinum, how were you able to identify it was a singleton pattern. care to educate me

Comment: Beans in  Spring are singleton by default. Unless otherwise specified.